# About 3 dimensional subspaces in the MOG

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I'm following [this](http://eprints.usm.my/6567/1/ON_STEINER_SYSTEM_S%285%2C_8%2C_24%29_AND_THE_MIRACLE_OCTAD_GENERATOR_%28MOG%29.pdf) (uncomplete) article as an expansion of Curtis' A new combinatorial approach to $M_{24}$.
Near its end, it's presented the $P$ and $L$ sets like this:

> Let Ω be a 24-element set. Let $\Lambda$ be an 8-element subset of $\Omega$ . $P(\Lambda)$ is a
> vector space over the field $Z_2$ under addition and scalar multiplication defined as
> above. Consider the following two 3-dimensional subspaces $P$ and $L$ of $P(\Lambda)$, whose members
> are all tetrads (4-element subsets) and P ∩ L = O (or o). There are $8 (= 2^3)$ tetrads in each 3-dimensional subspace of $P(\Lambda)$.

I'm struggling to understand why the tetrads can be seen as 3-dimensional subspaces of $P(\Lambda)$. I mean since $P(\Lambda)$ can be seen as a 8-dimensional vector space over $Z_2$, in my mind I'm thinking to the tetrads a **4-dimensional subspaces** and not as 3-dimensional ones.

I'm sure the article is correct in that claim, since also the original Curtis' one claims that, but it's to see why.

Few lines below, the article claims:

> Note that P is spanned by A, B and D

, so probably I'm thinking wrongly as the 4 tetrads elements as base element to span the space, while a triple of full tetrads is a base.

I mean: is there any relation between tetrads and 3-dim? For example, if we would have chosen couples instead of tetrads, what would have been the dimension of the subspace? Or triplets instead?

Can you help in understanding better that, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post complete article?

Comment: @Aqua, the complete article (which is a thesis) cannot be found on the net, I've googled it a lot, without success. So the only source is the one in the link above. About Curtis' article it's not for free, and it's protected by copyright. However the above thesis portion is enough to understand my question around pages 21 and 22, from where I quoted.

Answer (score 1):

I think to have understood the structure of the $3dim$ vector space described in the article, and I will show here tetrads are special ones to make a $3dim$ vector subspace of $P(\Lambda)$, since the only ones forming it.
First of all, let's recall the thm $2.1.16$ from the article:

> Theorem 2.1.16 The power set of $\Omega$ , $P(\Omega)$, is a vector space over field $Z_2$under addition defined as symmetric difference and scalar multiplication defined as: $\alpha x = x, \alpha=1$  or $\phi, \alpha=0$, where $\alpha\in Z_2$ and $x\in P(\Omega)$

Notice here the symmetric difference is the $XOR$, as told in logic jargon.

So let's start taking the tetrads $O$ and $A$ as seed. These two tetrads form a $1dim$ vector subspace of $P(\Lambda)$ over $Z_2$, since taking $\alpha=0$ we got $O$, while taking $\alpha=1$ we'd got $A$.

Now, using the symmetric difference, to get yet another tetrad from $A$ using a new tetrad $B$ we have to be sure the $|A+B|=2$, i.e. they have to share **exactly $2$ entries out of $4$**. By this we can be sure the 2 common entries cancel each other,  letting a plain new tetrad as result.
This is exactly what we got choosing the tetrad $B$ as done in the article. Here we have $A+B=C$, we a total of $4$ tetrads, including the $O$ one.
This is forming a $2dim$ vector subspace of $P(\Lambda)$ over $Z_2$. Notice $A$ and $B$ span this subspace.
But now we understood the trick, and we can cherry pick the tetrad $D$, with the condition $|A+D|=2$, $|B+D|=2$ and $|C+D|=2$. So, we finally easily check $A+D=E$, $B+D=F$ and $C+D=G$.
Together with $O$, here we have $8$ elements, which form a $3dim$ vector subspace of $P(\Lambda)$ over $Z_2$ (with $2^3$ elements), spanned by $A$, $B$ and $D$.

So far, so good. So it comes my doubt about "is there any special between the tetrads and the resulting $3dim$ vector space?".

We know the numbers of $1$ entries must be **even**, in order to have exactly its half as intersections for the symmetric difference above.
So we have 2 choices here: duads, or hexads.
Let's start from duads, choosing $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 0\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Now we can choose $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which shares only the top left entry, as needed. From these ones, we can get easily $C=A+B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which again has the good property to differ from $A$ and $B$ by one entry.

Actually, this form $2dim$ vector subspace of $P(\Lambda)$ over $Z_2$, spanned by $A$ and $B$. But now, if we try to find a $D$ duad which differ by one entry from all the other duads, we are failing, since we cannot find it. In a sense, the duads are not enough dense to produce new entries, as needed.
So, we cannot get a $3dim$ vector space by duads.

What about hexads? It's easy to check here we face the opposite problem: hexads are so dense, we cannot even find a $B$ differing by any $A$ by 3 entries, since hexads leave only two $0$ entries to move around.

So it seems tetrads are actually special in the sense they form the only $3dim$ vector subspace of $P(\Lambda)$ possible starting from a 8 elements $\Lambda$ set, under the symmetric difference and $Z_2$ tricks.

I was not able to demo it formally, but I think it can solve my doubt. If you can, please eventually post it as well, thanks.